# Regex to find ampersands without spaces on both sides

Tags: php, regex

I'm just trying to figure out the regex to find any ampersands that aren't immediately preceded and followed by a space. For example, it would find "asdf&asdf" and "asdf& asdf" but not "asdf & asdf"

This will be used in a preg_replace to add spaces before and after. (If you're wondering, the problem is that I'm stuck with a WYSIWYG that has a bug where it strips spaces on both sides of ampersands, and I need to manually add them back after the fact). Thoughts?

Comment: Thinking about this again - if you want to replace and add space, maybe you can search for `\s?&\s?`, and replace with ` & `. Even if you had space, it will still work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ampersand width not after a space or ampersand not before a space, but not both:

```
(?<!\s)&|&(?!\s)
```

Using lookaround, so this captures the ampersand only.

Answer (score 5):

```
(\S&\S|\s&\S|\S&\s)
```

- Non whitespace char, followed by & and another non space char
  `OR`
- Whitespace followed by &, followed by non space char
  `OR`
- Non whitespace char followed by &, followed by another whitespace char

Comment: To complete the answer, I believe the solution will be: `preg_replace('/(\S&\S|\s&\S|\S&\s)/', ' & ', $str);`

Answer (score 1):

To put space if it is not there on either side, can be done like this

```
echo preg_replace('/ ?& ?/',' & ','asdf&asdf asdf& asdf asdf & asdf');
//asdf & asdf asdf & asdf asdf & asdf
```

For without spaces on both sides (Answering to question title), it will fail on `asdf& asdf`

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<! )&(?! )/',' & ','asdf&asdf asdf& asdf asdf & asdf');
//asdf & asdf asdf& asdf asdf & asdf
```

Comment: Note that the OP wants a regex that matches an ampersand without space on one side _or_ the other (not necessarily both).

Comment: According to my tests, I finds only strings with a space neither before nor after.  What he wants is ampersands without both, not ampersands with neither.

Comment: I've put all three test strings into RegexBuddy, and it matches only the one with no spaces (the first one).

Comment: Added another one, the question title is confusing actually.

Answer (score 1):

Ampersand with non-space after or before:

```
(&[^ ]|[^ ]&)
```

Comment: Nice one, similar to mine, but much simpler, with no lookaround. You can also do `\S&|&\S`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to first find all ampersands independent of the characters to the left and right and then use a negative look behind assertion to ensure that not both characters are spaces.

```
.&.(?<! & )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([^\s]+&.+)|(.+&[^\s]+)
```

This regex makes sure that there is no space on the left xor the right of an `&` character

Comment: My attempt was similar, however, the OP states that the pattern should also match "asdf& asdf".  I believe this will not.

Answer (score 0):

It should work (not tested) : `/([^\s]&|&[^\s])/`. If you are only concerned about spaces and not "any blank character" : `/([^ ]&|&[^ ])/`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\s)\&\&\s
```

https://regex101.com/r/vBuuUf/1

hope it helps