# Why put a lookahead at the beginning, or a lookbehind at the end?

Tags: regex

I was trying to learn about positive/negative lookarounds, and I found [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973609/61624) that confused me:

> - Positive lookahead:
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> (?=REGEX_1)REGEX_2
> ```
>
> Match only if REGEX_1 matches; after matching REGEX_1, the match is
> discarded and searching for REGEX_2 starts at the same position.

Maybe this is really straightforward and obvious, but I can't comprehend it. If the syntax were `REGEX_2(?=REGEX_1)`, I'd understand, but not the way it's written.

Can someone explain what it means to have a lookahead at the beginning of a regex, how that differs from putting a lookahead at the end, and the value of doing so? I'd also like to ask the same question but about lookbehind at the end. I learn best from *concrete* examples. Thanks.

Comment: `(?=REGEX_1)` restricts a `REGEX_2` in `(?=REGEX_1)REGEX_2`, it means `REGEX_2` must start with `REGEX_1` pattern.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126137/regex-lookahead-ordering) should explain this all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, that seems on target. Reading it now. Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's definitely my question. I only partially understand the answer, so I left a comment. Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew did you mean to say "Lookbehind" in both sentences?

Comment: I see. Lookbehind asserts presence/absence of its pattern immediately to the left of the current location. Lookahead asserts presence/absence of its pattern immediately to the right of the current location.